# Optuna for Catboost outputs "trials" in random order?

Tags: python, catboost, optuna

I'm working on hyperparameter tuning using Optuna for CatboostRegressor, however I realised that the trials I'm getting are in random order (mine started with Trial 7 and then Trial 5 then Trial 8. All of the examples I see online are in order, for example Trial 0 finished with value: xxxxx, Trial 1, Trial 2... (Example: https://www.kaggle.com/saurabhshahane/catboost-hyperparameter-tuning-with-optuna)

Is this an issue or it's not something to worry about? Not sure why is mine in a random order though.

Also wondering if I should be doing `cb.cv` (Catboost's cross validation) instead of `cb.CatBoostRegressor` and then `.fit` and `.predict` for hyperparameter tuning? Or it doesn't matter which way I'm using to get the best hyperparameters?

[image]

This is my code:

```
def objective(trial):

    optuna_params = {"subsample": trial.suggest_float("subsample", 0.5, 0.99),
                     'od_wait': trial.suggest_int('od_wait', 10, 50, step=1),
                     "colsample_bylevel": trial.suggest_float("colsample_bylevel", 0.5, 0.99),
                     "random_strength": trial.suggest_int("random_strength", 1, 10, step=1),
                     "l2_leaf_reg": trial.suggest_float("l2_leaf_reg", 1.0, 50.0),
                     "max_depth": trial.suggest_int("max_depth", 4, 10, step=1),
                     "n_estimators": trial.suggest_int("n_estimators", 100, 2500, step=1),
                     'learning_rate': trial.suggest_loguniform("learning_rate", 0.005, 0.1)}

    cbregressor = cb.CatBoostRegressor(**optuna_params, 
                                       random_state=0,
                                       loss_function='MAE', 
                                       eval_metric='MAE', 
                                       one_hot_max_size=0,
                                       boost_from_average=True)
    
    cat_optuna = cbregressor.fit(cat_train_pool2, eval_set=cat_val_pool2, verbose=False, early_stopping_rounds=10)
    
    y_valid_pred_cat3 = cat_optuna.predict(X_validation2)
    
    MAE = mean_absolute_error(y_validation, y_valid_pred_cat3)
    print('MAE score of CatBoost =', MAE)
    return MAE
```

```
study = optuna.create_study(direction="minimize", sampler = TPESampler(seed=0), study_name="Catboost Optuna")
study.optimize(objective, n_trials=100, n_jobs=-1)
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is this an issue or it's not something to worry about? Not sure why is mine in a random order though.

No. When we set `n_jobs=-1` in `study.optimize` method, optimisation is performed parallelly using thread.

#### Regresser vs CV

I suppose either is fine. In general, when we use CV, overfitting is less likely to happen than single train/val split (i.e., regresser in this setting). However, the computing of CV cost is expensive.

Comment: I also have another question about optuna, it's my first time using optuna, have always been using Hyperopt :) In the output what does the numbers beside the timestamps mean? For example in the output above "037, 312, 584". Those are not the number of boosting rounds right? Because I was tuning n_estimators for the number of boosting rounds, which were returned in the updated best params (different from the numbers beside the timestamps).

Comment: You are right. These numbers are millisecond values