# Optuna - are the previous tuning results stored if I interrupt the kernel run?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, hyperparameters, optuna

I have been using Optuna to tune my hyperparameters for Catboostregressor. However I have set it to 100 iterations, due to having a large dataset it's taking a very long time to tune.

My code can be found here in my previous post: [Optuna for Catboost outputs "trials" in random order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69693929/optuna-for-catboost-outputs-trials-in-random-order/69694306#69694306)

Now it has reached 50 iterations, and I wish to stop it. I was wondering if I were to hit the "stop" button on jupyter notebook now, will I still be able to call my tuning params/output in my next cell using `study.best_params` and `study.best_trials`? Or it will throw me an error because I interrupted the tuning before 100% completion (keyboard interruption)?

I don't want to risk re-running everything again if it doesn't work because it took me almost a day to tune 50 trials, so I can't risk stopping it if I won't be able to generate call the params and trials from `study` in my next cell. I wanted to test this out myself but my tuning is still running on all CPUs so I'm afraid opening a new script will cause my whole system to crash. Appreciate if anyone knows the answer.

Answer (score 2):

No it won't save the results anywhere as these results are stored in ephemeral storage. What you would need is a persistent storage of the studies which can be achieved using the [RDB backend](https://optuna.readthedocs.io/en/v1.1.0/tutorial/rdb.html). This option allows you to make use of a database to store the study results such as the `best_params`, `best_trial`, `best_value`, and `trials`. Think of it as an experiment tracking tool builtin to optuna.

Comment: Hi @yudhiesh thanks for the suggestion. I guess in my case it's too late as I did not set the RDB backend when I ran my code yesterday? The tuning is still running now, which means the only way is to wait for it to reach 100%? Else I won't have anything in the end if I interrupt the kernel before it reaches 100%. I think it will take another 24 hours or so...

Comment: Yup sadly you can't do anything right now. Maybe a better tool for this would be [mlflow](https://www.mlflow.org/docs/latest/index.html) if you have the time to setup, which is what I use and is meant for experiment tracking.

Comment: thanks so much! I will set the RDB next time. Didn't know about it earlier and didn't expect the tuning to run for more than a day too.